# Dúvida com o Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Comecei a aprender `JSF` e instalei o **Tomcat**, porém quando inicializo ele aparece essa mensagem:

> Port 8080 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in
>   use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system
>   process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to
>   stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Gostaria de saber como fazer para mudar isso.

Comment: Qual seu sistema operacional?

Answer (score 1):

O problema de conflito poderá ser resolvido de duas maneiras: a primeira é identificando o outro software que já está utilizando a porta 8080 e a segunda maneira seria:

1. Localize a instalação do Apache Tomcat. Entre em seu diretório;
2. Entre no diretório /conf;
3. Como usuário root, abra o arquivo server.xml; Por exemplo:

Caso seja LINUX: # gedit server.xml
Caso seja Windows abra com o bloco de notas ou compatível

4. Com o arquivo aberto, pesquise(Ctrl+F) por 8080;
5. Mude para alguma porta de sua escolha. Vale salientar que faça uso de um porta em que nenhum serviço faça uso;
6. Salve e feche o arquivo.